# No reconoce los elementos de boostrap-vue

Tags: bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

Ese es el codigo que he utilizado para usar la dependencia de boostrap en mi app

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Import Bootstrap an BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Comment: Muestra también el mensaje de error, _como texto_.

Comment: ese codigo donde lo pusiste?

Comment: Gracias ya he podido solucionarlo, habia que importar bootstrap desde el Main.js